# Is this a good function for I2C receive?

Tags: i2c, c, data

I'm trying to fix my I2C code:

Is the following function correct because it has multiple returns. I don't know if that would work.

```
uint8_t I2C_rx(uint8_t ack_rx)
{
    uint8_t i;
    if (ack_rx)
    {
        TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWEA); // sending ACK
        while (!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));
        return TWDR;
    }
    else
    {
        TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN);           // sending NACK
        while (!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));
        return TWDR;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can have multiple returns. Some people disagree on style grounds, but it works as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem with multiple returns but it could be reduced to:

```
uint8_t I2C_rx(bool ack_rx)
{
  uint8_t cr = (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEN);
  if (ack_rx) cr |= (1<<TWEA);
  TWCR = cr;
  while (!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));
  return TWDR;
}
```

or

```
uint8_t I2C_rx(bool ack_rx)
{
  TWCR = (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEN) | (ack_rx<<TWEA);
  while (!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));
  return TWDR;
}
```

Cheers!